# correct use of html for generating query

Tags: html

I have a html, in which I am taking input from user and when hitting search button it is creating a query

```
<form class="content" style="margin-left:0px !important" action="/searchCall/">
    <div class="workplace">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="head clearfix">
                    <div class="isw-documents"></div>
                    <h1>Project Specific</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="block-fluid">
                    <div class="row-form clearfix">
                        <div class="span3">List Of KPI Messages:</div>
                        <div class="span4">
                            <select multiple="multiple" name="KPI" id="from" size="10">
                                <option value="101">FTP Upload</option>
                                <option value="103">FTP Download</option>
                                option value="105">HTTP Test</option>
                                <option value="107">HTTPS Test</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="span5"></div>
                            <input style="width:32%;" id="btn" class="btn btn-large" type="submit" value="Search ">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

when I hit the submit button, URL generate is

```
http://192.168.2.253:8080/searchCall/?startDate=DD-MM-YYYY&endDate=DD-MM-YYYY&reportingType=0&circle=0&kpi=101&kpi=103&kpi=107
```

I want to make

```
kpi=101&kpi=103&kpi=107
```

to

```
kpi= [101,102,107]
```

is there any way to do that.

Comment: Not with pure HTML, no.

Comment: is there any way to make 101,102 and 107 in a same name.

Comment: **Not with pure HTML, no.** – The URL query format is standardised and hardcoded, you cannot change it using only HTML.

Comment: is there any alternate for doing this,

Comment: You can formulate any format you want using Javascript. But you should not be introducing Javascript into the mix just for this tiny aesthetic reason. Why do you insist on this particular format?

Comment: There's no need to do this on the client side. The code on the server side should handle this very common problem, often by making kpi an array. This is an XY problem.

Comment: need to make things easier for the backend side ,anyways thanks @deceze.

Comment: What backend are you using? Again, this is very common.

Comment: I am using django as a backend server

Comment: I've not used Django in particular but Python in general, and usually Python has perfectly fine support for this standard format and will parse it into an array just fine.

Comment: can you suggest me how to do that in python.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Comment: use `kpi[]=101&kpi[]=103&kpi[]=107` this explicitly states as array and PHP and even javascript url readers will decode to array correctly

Comment: @NikosM. — No, it doesn't. That's a PHP convention, nothing more. Most form parsing libraries don't require special naming conventions to get an array out of duplicate key names in a query string.